Можно ли скачивать только аудио из hls плейлиста?
У меня есть hls плейлист с видеосегментами, я могу скачать из каждого видеосегмента только аудио (я знаю как это сделать через тот же ffmpeg).
Но тут появляются главные вопросы:
Скачивая только аудио ffmpeg формально скачивает весь сегмент (видеодорожку) и преобразовывает её в аудио "на лету" или действительно скачивает лишь аудиодорожку, меньше ли тратится трафика при этом?
Если нет есть ли вообще способы скачать из видеосегмента из плейлиста HLS только аудио?
